# How to scale images in android?

Tags: android, animation, scale

I have 5 images in my activity.
I want to scale each big image and re-scale it to small size one by one in a thread.
I am newbie in android so please give me some sort of example which can help me better understad.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765899/out-of-memory-error-with-bitmap/16766123#16766123 and this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: can you please provide the code of how you are getting your images in the first place?

Comment: I have edited my question for a clearer concept. pls have a look

Comment: I have my images in drawable folder.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap srcBitmap, int newWidth,
        int newHeight) {
    try {
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcBitmap, newWidth, newHeight,
                true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

In Activity:

```
ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(bitmapImage, 120, 120));
```