# Please help solve these exceptions, android?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

This is logcat of my app

```
  07-11 11:31:25.269: D/-heap(6666): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1256K, 13% free 28316K/32227K, paused 34ms
  07-11 11:31:25.309: D/-heap(6666): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 414K, 14% free 27901K/32227K, paused 42ms
  07-11 11:31:25.309: E/dalvikvm-heap(6666): Out of memory on a 20155408-byte allocation.
  07-11 11:31:25.309: I/dalvikvm(6666): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
  07-11 11:31:25.309: I/dalvikvm(6666):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40b01c58 self=0x1640e80
  07-11 11:31:25.309: I/dalvikvm(6666):   | sysTid=6666 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074922856
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=351 stm=36 core=0
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:306)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:331)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at com.callplanets.chat.ui.Talk$DiscussArrayAdapter.getView(Talk.java:939)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2045)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:705)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.ListView.correctTooHigh(ListView.java:1395)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1333)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1615)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1875)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:930)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1653)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1511)
  07-11 11:31:25.319: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1416)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1490)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2455)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
  07-11 11:31:25.329: I/dalvikvm(6666):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  07-11 11:31:26.399: E/dalvikvm(6666): can't open /data/misc/hprof_oom_dump.hprof: Permission denied
  07-11 11:31:26.419: D/-heap(6666): Dump of hprof is not done
  07-11 11:31:26.419: D/skia(6666): --- decoder->decode returned false
  07-11 11:31:26.419: W/dalvikvm(6666): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b009f0)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:306)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:331)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at com.callplanets.chat.ui.Talk$DiscussArrayAdapter.getView(Talk.java:939)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2045)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:705)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.ListView.correctTooHigh(ListView.java:1395)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1333)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1615)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1875)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:930)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1653)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1511)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1416)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1490)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2455)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
  07-11 11:31:26.429: E/AndroidRuntime(6666):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

These are the main exceptions:
07-11 11:31:25.309: E/dalvikvm-heap(6666): Out of memory on a 20155408-byte allocation.
07-11 11:31:26.399: E/dalvikvm(6666): can't open /data/misc/hprof_oom_dump.hprof: Permission denied

How can i solve these issue?
Please tell....

I have an activity on which i show thumbnail of an image picked from gallery.
On the click of the thumbnail take user to another activity and display the regular size.

On the back of 2nd activity this exception occurs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765899/out-of-memory-error-with-bitmap/16766123#16766123. check this

Answer (score 1):

By Reducing/Scale size of the Image you can get rid out of the Out of Memory Exception, Try this

`BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inSampleSize = 8; 
 Bitmap receipt = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.toString(),options);  //From File You can customise on your needs.`