# Grid view crashe the app on scrolling on too many images

Tags: android, image, gridview, out-of-memory, adapter

in my project that uses custom adapter with grid view , when my grid view load many Items that contain images on scrolling my activity crashes and reloads again. it had some resource problem on loading image that i solved with help of @Raghunandan
my error is out of memmory. cause i think loadfull size images.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StructureCase> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater           = null;
    public Context         context;
    public Class           distinationActivity = null;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<StructureCase> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       // mInflater = (LayoutInflater)G.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
       public ImageView gem_img   = null;
       public TextView  gem_name   = null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final View v;

        final StructureCase item = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_grid_list,  null);
            //mInflater = (LayoutInflater)G.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_grid_list, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            viewHolder.gem_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_mygrid_list);
            viewHolder.gem_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_mygrid_list);

            viewHolder.gem_name.setTypeface(G.typeFacePrs);

        } else {
           viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        int temp = 0;

        viewHolder.gem_name.setText(item.g_name);




int id = G.currentActivity.getResources().getIdentifier(item.g_image, "drawable", G.currentActivity.getPackageName());
        Drawable drawable = G.currentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(id);
        if(drawable != null){
        viewHolder.gem_img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }else{
            viewHolder.gem_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.almas);

        }



        //viewHolder.newsThumb.setImageResource(temp);

        viewHolder.gem_img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: I guess this is where you have a problem `Drawable drawable = G.currentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(id);`

Comment: before runnig activity I set the G.currentActivity so I hace contex in all app by call G.currentActivity.this . so how i can solve?

Comment: the problem is the drawable resource is not found. also you don't need this `convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_grid_list,  null);`

Comment: I update the adapter and add "if" to check if drawable is null fill with another image. but still have problem.

Comment: What is MyAdapter line 87?

Comment: what is on line 87 in MyAdapter.java is what i meant. That is  before the update.

Comment: do u mean "Drawable drawable = G.currentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(id);"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49397/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-kenji)

Comment: ok that problem is solved, but main problem is still remains and i updated the question and problem of out of memmory.

Comment: the docs as an example of how to scale down the images

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765899/out-of-memory-error-with-bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to in your `getview method` while setting bitmap in `ImageView`.

```
private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException
 {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 800;

            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) 
                {
                    break;
                }
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;`enter code here`
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
        }
```