# @drawable in the xml file cause the app to crash

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-drawable

I am trying to add a background image to the activity by `android:background=@drawable/..` as shown in the code below. But the problem is, when i add this line `android:background="@drawable/introbackground"` the app crashs, and when i delete it the app works normally.

To note: the image i use, i have resized it so that, it fits the entire screen. is this could be the problem?

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/introbackground"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.meetingpointlocator_03" 
>
```

LOGCAT OutPut:

```
05-10 08:06:24.101: D/dalvikvm(17707): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 119K, 15% free 9922K/11580K, 
paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-10 08:06:24.101: I/dalvikvm-heap(17707): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for   
121925780-byte allocation
05-10 08:06:24.131: D/dalvikvm(17707): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 15% free 9912K/11580K,  
paused 30ms, total 30ms
05-10 08:06:24.131: E/dalvikvm-heap(17707): Out of memory on a 121925780-byte   
allocation.
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 
obj=0x41c96578 self=0x41c1ca60
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   | sysTid=17707 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps   
handle=1074503676
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   | state=R schedstat=( 107360003 8309669 119 ) 
utm=6 stm=4 core=1
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at      
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at  
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at 
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at 
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at  
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3563)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>
(ViewGroup.java:475)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>  
(LinearLayout.java:176)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init> 
(LinearLayout.java:172)
 05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at     
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.Intro.onCreate(Intro.java:38)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
05-10 08:06:24.131: I/dalvikvm(17707):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
```

Comment: What you get in logcat ?

Comment: you can't post crash questions without posting the error from your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Out of memory on a 121925780-byte allocation.

You app ran out of memory.

> To note: the image i use, i have resized it so that, it fits the
>   entire screen. is this could be the problem?

Yes the likely cause is this background image which needs to be scaled down. Each app is allocated a certain heap size. As of android 3.0 and above bitmap pixel data is stored in the heap. You need to scale down the image.

[Out of Memory error with Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765899/out-of-memory-error-with-bitmap)

Also read **Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory**

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

You are getting OOM i.e out of memory and also the inflator exception at

```
android:background="@drawable/introbackground"
```

because the image **introbackground** is of very large size.

## Solution

```
 Use a .jpeg light weight image insted of using .png heavy image.
```