# Error when creating Bitmap from an image

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to draw an image from a file, a png file.
I need to draw it as a bitmap on a canvas but i cant get the file into the bitmap object without getting an error, after trying for a lot of time i need some help.

example of what i tried:

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.myimage);
```

thanks!

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Ignore your error and try something different. (Or post the error and lets solve it)

Comment: You likely need to reduce the resolution of your image. I am assuming you are running out of memory because you are trying to load a high res image which creates a large memory load for your app. There are tons of questions on SO about it here is one from a quick Google search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765899/out-of-memory-error-with-bitmap